Redis on Docker never close file handle, leading to full disk (100% disk usage in df)
I have a docker running redis server as slave instance on a Ubuntu server, production instance.
This server always have disk full, although checking disk usage (using du) never show anything use the space. Eventually, I found out that redis is not closing open file handle, leading to disk usage to always increase until disk full. Using command lsof | grep deleted would show the file handles remain open.
enter image description here
The only way I can release this open file handle is by restarting the redis instance. I am using command sudo docker exec -it slave redis-cli shutdown to restart it. And after restarting the redis server, I use command sudo docker exec -it slave redis-cli config set save "" to disable writing to disk.
However, I have to log into the server once in a while just to run this commands.
Is there any way I can configure the redis server to always close open file handle? Or any kind of solution for this issue?
